# Problem with changing a name of “References” section

Tags: bibliographies

I am trying to convert tittle of bibliography to "SomeName", but the following code block doesn't work :/ I mean the bibliography is printed but with the wrong tittle.

```
 \begin{document} 
 \begin{thebibliography}{9}
 \renewcommand{\refname}{SomeName} 
 \bibitem{slave} 
 \url{google.com}
 \end{thebibliography}  
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please tell us which document class you employ. Some document classes use `\refname` to store the name of the bibliography, others use `\bibname`, or whatever. A separate comment: You should most definitely redefine `\refname` (or `\bibname`, or whatever) *before*, not after, running `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`.

Comment: My documentclass is: \documentclass[12pt, a4paper]{article}

Comment: What happens if you place `\renewcommand{\refname}{SomeName}` before rather than after `\begin{thebibliography}{9}`?

Comment: Then it works. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

The `article` document class provides the following (greatly simplified) definition of the `thebibliography` environment:

```
\newenvironment{thebibliography}[1]
     {\section*{\refname}%
      ...}
     {...}
```

where `...` denotes "other stuff". The `article` document class also provides the following definition of `\refname`:

```
\newcommand\refname{References}
```

What's the upshot of all this? Well, for the redefinition of `\refname`, say,

```
\renewcommand{\refname}{SomeName}
```

to affect the appearance of the unnumbered section-level header that's typeset at the start of the bibliography, the redefinition must occur *before*, not after, the `\begin{thebibliography}{9}` statement.